# Is it possible to determine what branch the current branch is being merged into using the current and target branch commit hashes?

Tags: git

Currently I have access to two commit hashes one being for the current branch and the other being the target branch. However, I am trying to get the name of the target branch to determine if the current branch is being merged into 'master' or 'main'.

I have done some research already and tried working with `git branch --contains target_head_commit_hash` but my concern is that this may return multiple branches (excluding my own denoted with a '*') making it hard to know which one my branch is being merged into.

All help is much appreciated and if you wish to write a small code snippet showcasing your solution I am working in Python :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git symbolic-ref -q --short HEAD` is the current branch name if there is one. Merging is done on commits. Which branch tip gets updated isn't relevant to the work itself, it's not needed to do the merge and Git's convenience commands always use `HEAD` as the first parent. If `HEAD` is a symbolic ref, well, hey presto, that's "the current branch". That's all it is.

Put another way: two commit id's are enough to do the merge, if you want to know what name gets updated afterwards it's `HEAD`, which is often best left attached to some branch name.

Comment: This is before the merge. I just need to know the name of the branch the "current branch" is being merged into only using the two commit hashes. I'm not sure if I'm understanding what you are saying. But I do appreciate the feedback as I am not very familiar with the git command line tool.

Comment: You're making this too complicated. The structure Git operates on is a dag of committed snapshots, branch (and all other kinds of ref) names are just labels hung on that graph. Git has no required or unambiguous or permanent mapping from a commit id to any name. Commits and their history matter. Names, what you or anyone chooses to call them, don't.

Comment: From what I understand you are saying the solution would be to look at what HEAD points to after the merge. But my question does not involve merging. Given two commit hashes (before merging) how can I determine if my current branch is being merged into master/main (before merging). If the current branch is NOT being merged into master/main then I will refuse the merge. I just need to get the name of the target branch.

Comment: Your current checkout is what's being merged into. If you've got a branch checked out, HEAD points at the same branch ref before and after the merge. You can't answer your question given just the commits' hashes, you have to look at the ref merge is going to update, HEAD, and whether it's attached to a branch tip that points at one of them.

Comment: If you want to find the name used to pick the other tip, that's recorded only in the default MERGE_MSG, `cat .git/MERGE_MSG`.

Answer (score 0):

The one way I know is that you can know that in commit message, which is basically auto-generated so it contains the target and current branch like - `Merge branch 'branch1' into master`

Comment: How would I get access to this commit message via git using the information I have above (current branch hash and target branch hash)? Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you have committed the change then you can find it in git log also in this case you can try `git log --first-parent` which will list the commits and its first parent. Incase if you have not committed the changes then the current branch is the branch in which your changes are getting merged.

Comment: But does this work prior to merging? The current branch has not yet been merged into the target. I'm trying to figure out the name of the target branch before this merge can happen.

Comment: That's what I was asking you. All I have is the two commit hashes and I'm trying to figure out what command(s) I could use to determine the name of the target branch (the one current is going to be merged into). I'm not actually merging these branches until I know the name of the target branch.